# Symfony get single form field post value in controller method

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm using symfony 2.8, I'm submitting a registration from to registerAction method. I'm getting all my submitted data like this when I use `$form-getdata()` in registerAction method.

```
AppBundle\Entity\User Object
(
    [id:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
    [name:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => testname
    [email:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => test@test.com
    [roles:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => Admin User
    [plainPassword:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 123456
    [password:AppBundle\Entity\User:private] => 
)
```

I have used `$request->request->get('name')` to get single name value but it is showing blank screen and printing nothing.

My html form looks like this on viewing source code in browser.

```
<form name="user" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div><label for="user_name" class="required">Name</label><input type="text" id="user_name" name="user[name]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div><label for="user_email" class="required">Email</label><input type="email" id="user_email" name="user[email]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div><label for="user_roles" class="required">Roles</label><select id="user_roles" name="user[roles]" class="form-control" style="margin:5px 0;"><option value="Normal User">Normal User</option><option value="Admin User">Admin User</option></select></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div><label for="user_plainPassword_first" class="required">Password</label><input type="password" id="user_plainPassword_first" name="user[plainPassword][first]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div><label for="user_plainPassword_second" class="required">Repeat Password</label><input type="password" id="user_plainPassword_second" name="user[plainPassword][second]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
            </div>
            <div><button type="submit" id="user_Register" name="user[Register]" class="btn btn-success form-control">Register</button></div><input type="hidden" id="user__token" name="user[_token]" value="epZFHVctxHFlsnxG-H4OdS92DmGVjP1DDF-bKJrV2Ss" />
    </form>
```

How can I get single posted form value.?

Comment: try `$request->request->get('user')` there should be an array with all values

Comment: Yes its showing showing array, but is there any way to fetch the value directly

Comment: First of all, why do you need single value? (maybe there is a better way to do what you are trying) Second, if you are creating form type and passing User Object, you can just do `Object->getvalue` after handleRequest

Comment: I need single data for some check conditions, I'm new to symfony Could you please tell me why it is created user array in the form, how can i remove user array, I have created this form in the controller using "FormBuilderInterface" interface.

Comment: You can maybe use custom validators to do checks, user array is created because your name is `name="user[roles]"`

Comment: How can I achieve this in the form without user array 
"<input type="email" id="user_email" name="email" required="required" class="form-control" />"

Comment: You can't with form interface, there will always be a wrapper that is the form name. I suggest to you to read http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: also maybe read about forms https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Comment: Ok thanks @kunicmarko20

Answer (score 1):

If `$request->request->get('{form_name}')` returns an array with your form data, then you can access the specific input field with `$request->request->get('user')['name']`. But you should use form classes instead, where you can define all of necessary fields with validation constraints, etc. Hope this helps!